# Mostrar Count de un Query en un Label

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

Que tal, estoy tratando de mostrar el resultado de un query en el que cuento los resultados dependiendo del where

mi query esta en una carpeta llamada `conexiones` y dentro tiene una clase llamada `conexion-general` en esa clase realizo el query de esta manera:

```
public class conteo_maint
    {
        public DataTable countconnect()
        {
            string myConnectionString = @"C:\\Users\\gutiece\\Desktop\\database\\" + "Database1.accdb";

            DataTable CouMaiTable = new DataTable();

            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
                bool ok = System.IO.File.Exists(myConnectionString);
                String qry = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM status_change WHERE area = maintenance";
                String allqry = "SELECT * FROM status_change WHERE area = maintenance";
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = qry;
                command.CommandText = allqry;

                adapter.SelectCommand = command;

                command.Connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); // close conn after 
                CouMaiTable.Load(reader);
                if (!reader.IsClosed)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }

                return CouMaiTable;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return CouMaiTable;
        }
    }
```

tengo los dos querys con la finalidad de que uno solo muestre el total y el otro poder llenar un `GridView`.

despues tengo `dashboard.aspx` en la cual es donde quiero mostrar el resultado de `count`. en el `Backend` mando a llamar a la case de `conteo_maint` de esta manera:

```
conexiones.conteo_maint countconnect = new conexiones.conteo_maint();
conexiones.conteo_maint CouMaiTable = new conexiones.conteo_maint();
```

y quiero que el resultado del conteo se muestre en este `label`:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                  Messages <span class="badge">
                      <asp:Label Text="text" runat="server"  id="Lbl_notu"/></span>
                </button>&nbsp
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y la pregunta es?

Comment: @Pikoh pues como puedo mostrar el `count` o major dicho su resultado, en el label tomando en cuenta que `Dashboard` y `conexion-general` estan en diferentes lados

Comment: para empezar.. la funcion countconnect esta mal.. ejecutas dos querys (mentira solo ejecutas uno) y devuelves un solo valor..  en ningun lado estas haciendo nada con el count (que no estas haciendo)

Comment: @gbianchi si supuse que no se realizaria el count y pense que se solucionaria creandolo con diferentes variables pero ahora que lo dices me doy cuenta que command se reemplaza por el Segundo query (Gracias por hacerme ver eso) en todo caso, ya arregle eso, y suponiendo que ya lo hice y se realiza el count como lo puedo mostrar en el label?

Comment: es que hay errores de concepto? conexiones.conteo_maint countconnect = new conexiones.conteo_maint(); y en la linea que sigue, solo dimensionas la clase.. donde haces esto? cual es el problema de hacer Lbl_notu.text = countconnect .countconnect? y ademas ahora tu clase deberia devolver un valro y no un datatable

Comment: tienes razon, tendras algun link para leer mas acerca de eso? ¿como debo hacer para que devuelva un valor, y no un DataTable? y si coloco Lbl_notu.Text = countconnect.countconnect no funciona ya que me tira un error Error `Cannot convert method group 'countconnect' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?`

Comment: lo que quiero es mostrar ese count como si fuera una notificacion (en realidad no lo es!)

Answer (score 0):

No te hace falta hacer dos `queries`. Simplemente con la de `allqry` tendrías bastante.

Devolviendo esto, luego en tu `code-behind` de `dashboard.aspx`, simplemente haz un

`Lbl_notu.Text = CouMaiTable.Rows.Count` y te dirá cuantas filas tiene.